# Div element looks strange on phone

Tags: html, css

I have 3 div side by side, my problem is that they don't appear as I intended on a mobile phone. The page looks like it should be on a laptop/wide screen.

Here is the page:

[http://dennissøderkvist.dk/?page_id=35](http://denniss%C3%B8derkvist.dk/?page_id=35)

So you see there is the div with a contact formular, a div with the google map, and a div with address info. If you open it on a mobile phone, it looks horrible, the last div at the end jumps down. How can I solve this?

Here is my css:

```
    #conHolderDiv 
{   
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
}

#mapHolderDiv
{
    float: left;
    width:40%;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

#adrDiv
{
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
}
```

The `conHolderDiv` is the first div, that holds the contactform. The `mapHolderDiv` is the div that holds the map, and the `adrDiv` holds the address

Comment: Are you using a responsive (or any other) CSS framework, such as Bootstrap?

Comment: Try applying some responsivity to it and make the divs be side by side on big screens and one below the other on mobile devices. You can use a library like [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/). It has a grid system that'll suit your needs.

Comment: I'm not sure really. I just added to the custom css section that the theme allows

Comment: You can also use [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) which is way smaller in size and it's a nice starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously mentioned, you could use Bootstrap. Or learn about responsive design.

For your example, with the three column layout you are on about you can use Media Queries to target `divs` that meet certain screen sizes.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1000px) {

  #conHolderDiv, #mapHolderDiv, #adrDiv {
     float:none;
     width:100%
  }

}
```

This will give you a 1x3 layout, rather than 3x3. We are not floating the elements, and assigning a width that takes up 100% of the space.

Answer (score 1):

or you can always use `display:table`

```
<div style="display:table; width:100%;">
  <div style="display:table-row">
     <div id="conHolderDiv"></div>
     <div id="mapHolderDiv"></div>
     <div id="adrDiv"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the css will be

```
#conHolderDiv {   
  display:table-cell;
  width: 35%;
}

#mapHolderDiv {
  display:table-cell;
  width:40%;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

#adrDiv {
  display:table-cell;
  width: 20%;
}
```